# Size of vector of vector c++

Tags: c++, memory, vector, sizeof

I'm trying to estimate the size in memory of a vector of a vector, but it seems I don't get the correct approximation.

Here is the small code I wrote to check :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        size_t n = 100;
        size_t m = 1000000;

        float sizeInKB = (sizeof(vector<vector<int> >) + n*sizeof(vector<int>) + n*m*sizeof(int))/1024.0f;
        cout << sizeInKB << " KB" << endl;

        vector<vector<int> > vect(n);

        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
                vect[i].resize(m);
        }

        while(true)
        {}

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As output, I get 390 630 KB, whereas the application takes 394 588 KB in memory according to the task manager. I agree that this is not the best way to know how much memory is used by the application (and especially by the vector) but it gives a good hint, and 4 MB is not only a few KB.

Now if I try to estimate the size in memory of a vector of vector of vector, it gets more and more messy. With the same code, replacing `int` by `vector<int>` :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        size_t n = 100;
        size_t m = 1000000;

        float sizeInKB = (sizeof(vector<vector<vector<int> > >) + n*sizeof(vector<vector<int> >) + n*m*sizeof(vector<int>))/1024.0f;
        cout << sizeInKB << " KB" << endl;

        vector<vector<vector<int> > > vect(n);

        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
                vect[i].resize(m);
        }

        while(true)
        {}

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As output I get 4 687 500 KB, whereas the application takes 6 271 028 KB in memory according to the task manager. There is a difference of more than 1.5 GB ... Where is this overhead coming from ? Is there a way to compute it ?

I'm running all of this on Windows 7 Pro 64 bits, with Visual Studio 2008 ...

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Remember that the operating system needs space for its housekeeping as well, page tables, memory maps, stacks, etc.

Comment: And even more so in a Debug build, you should compare the Debug and Release results.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the size of the integer storage in the second code.

Comment: @tinman: But each of the inner vector (3rd dimension) contains zero elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second case, every single of your `n * m` elements is a `vector<int>`, which has to be dynamically allocated. Each such dynamic allocation has an overhead. It is not unusual to find dynamic allocations having a 32-64 byte overhead. This is highly likely part of the reason for your "missing" bytes.

Comment: But even in the first case, if I take `size_t m = 50000000` the expected size is 19.531 GB and the memory used is 19.572 GB ... Housekeeping of the operating system then ?

Comment: In the first case, you have 100 vectors of `m` vectors of `int`. There is only 100 vector overheads for this, each containing 1M integers. In the second case, you have 100M vectors of `int`, which each has it's own storage for `int`. Without knowing how the internal representation of `vector<int>` is defined, we can't say how much memory each allocation takes, but it's a fair estimate to say that there will be some overhead.

Comment: Could it be possible that the overhead depends on the size of the allocated vector (cf first case, with m = 50M) ?

Comment: Note that 50M means 200MB per allocation, so the overhead would be very small in this case. The overhead consists of two things: the admin block that `new`/`delete` or `malloc`/`free` uses to keep track of "what was allocated", and a rounding up of the block size to some alignment size, typically 8 or 16 bytes. So for an allocation of 200MB, the percentage overhead is minute. In the case of a small allocation, the percentage overhead is much larger. In your second case, you have LOTS of little allocation.

Comment: It seems the overhead is about 16 bytes per vector indeed (1.6 "missing" GB / 100 M vectors ~= 16 B per vector) ... But I guess this is implementation-based, and is most likely to be different on each system